# Error on the map function: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I know this question has been asked again, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong because no solution is working for me.
my code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then((json) => {
        setItems(json.items);
      })

      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }, []);

  if (loading) {
    return <p>Data is loading...</p>;
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ul>
        {items.map((item) => (
          <li key={item.id}>
            name: {item.name} | email: {item.email}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I tried to write it liek this too, to check if the array exists and i dont get and error but I dont get anything as a result :

```
{items?.map((item) => (
          <li key={item.id}>
            name: {item.name} | email: {item.email}
          </li>
        ))}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello looking at the jsonplaceholders documentation you need to first transform the response with json() when fetching like this

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then((response) => { 
        return response.json() // return response.json() first
      })
      .then((json) => { 
        setItems(json) // then set the json into the items
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }, []);
```

Without the converting it to json first the you set the response object instead of the json array

Answer (score 1):

you need to convert first the response to json and then set to state.

```
fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then((res) => res.json()).then((data) => {
        setItems(data);
      })
```

From [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch), `fetch` does **not** directly return the `JSON` response body but instead returns a promise that resolves with a `Response` object. The `Response` object, in turn, does **not** directly contain the actual `JSON` response body but is instead a representation of the entire HTTP response. So, to extract the JSON body content from the Response object, use the `json()` method, which returns a second promise that resolves with the result of parsing the response body text as `JSON`.

Answer (score 1):

[Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) returns a [response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) which you need to turn into JSON before using it.

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
  .then((res) => {
    res.json();
  })
  .then((items) => {
    setItems(items);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  })
  .finally(() => {
    setLoading(false);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

check this code out

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async() => {
    setLoading(true)
    const res = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
    const data = await res.json();
    setLoading(false);
    setItems(data);
    }
    fetchData()

  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change useState to this:
`const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);`
On first load App function return before useEffect undefined code.

If it still does not work add question mark before accesing prop. Like this:

```
<ul>
     {items?.map((item) => (
        <li key={item?.id}>
            name: {item?.name} | email: {item?.email}
         </li>
     ))}
</ul>
```

Adding question mark makes it optional.

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code:

```
<ul>
  {items?.map((item) => (
    <li key={item?.id}>
      name: {item?.name} | email: {item?.email}
    </li>
  ))}
</ul>
```